# How do you implement a Higher-Order-Component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to set up a HOC in React to able to apply text selection detection to any Input component. However I seem to be missing something when I was trying to put it together.

I was following this article here on how to create a HOC:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-react-higher-order-components-by-example-95e8c47c8006

My code (before the article looked like this):

```
import { func } from 'prop-types';
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Input } from 'reactstrap';

class SelectableInput extends PureComponent {
    handleMouseUp = () => {
        const selection = window.getSelection();

        if (selection) {
            this.props.onSelectionChanged(selection.toString());
        }
    };

    render() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        const { onSelectionChanged, ...rest } = this.props;
        return <Input onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp} {...rest} />;
    }
}

SelectableInput.propTypes = {
    onSelectionChanged: func
};

export default SelectableInput;
```

And I was using it like this:

```
    render() {
        return (
                <SelectableInput
                    type="textarea"
                    name="textarea-input"
                    value={'This is some txt'}
                    onSelectionChanged={onTextSelectionChanged}
                    id="textarea-input"
                    onChange={e => this.onPageDataChanged(e)}
                    dir="rtl"
                    rows="14"
                    placeholder="Placeholder..."
                />
        );
    }
```

After reading the article I changed the above code to:

```
const SelectableInput = WrappedInput => {
    class SelectableInputHOC extends PureComponent {
        handleMouseUp = () => {
            const selection = window.getSelection();

            if (selection) {
                this.props.onSelectionChanged(selection.toString());
            }
        };

        render() {
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            const { onSelectionChanged, ...rest } = this.props;
            return <WrappedInput onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp} {...rest} />;
        }
    }

    SelectableInputHOC.propTypes = {
        onSelectionChanged: func
    };
};

export default SelectableInput;
```

My question is how do I actually go about using it now in a render() function?

Thank you for your advance for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to not follow the official (and quite) excellent guide? https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectableInput is a function that returns a function that takes a component as a parameter and returns another component. You can use it like this:

```
const ResultComponent = ({...props}) =>
    SelectableInput({...props})(YourParamComponent);
```

Then render ResultComponent wherever you want.

Here you have an example of using a HOC and passing props to it:

https://jsfiddle.net/58c7tmx2/

HTML:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

JS

```
const YourParamComponent = ({ name }) => <div>Name: {name}</div>

const SelectableInput = ({...props}) =>
    WrappedInput => <WrappedInput {...props} />

const ResultComponent = ({...props}) =>
    SelectableInput({...props})(YourParamComponent);

const App = () => <ResultComponent name="textarea-input" />

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you give me a small snippet of how I would use it with props? For example with:
```
                    type="textarea"
                    name="textarea-input"
```

How would I declare the YourParamComponent with the props? Can you show me a snippet in a render() function?

Comment: Sure, I just added an example and his jsfiddle. Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you upvote my anser rhaq? (is the up arrow) Thanks.

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. (I'm new here)